# Is there "Attention Is All You Need" implementation in Keras?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, keras, machine-translation

Has anyone seen [this model's](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762) implementation **using Keras**?

**inb4**: [tensorflow](https://github.com/Kyubyong/transformer), [pytorch](https://github.com/jadore801120/attention-is-all-you-need-pytorch)

Comment: You can find a version here: https://github.com/Lsdefine/attention-is-all-you-need-keras - Seems reasonable but I just briefly looked at the code so I can't guarantee it is exactly what its in the paper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://pypi.org/project/keras-transformer/) is an implementation from PyPI.

Answer (score 2):

Update for anyone googling this in 2021: Keras has implemented a [MultiHead attention layer](https://keras.io/api/layers/attention_layers/multi_head_attention/). If key, query, and value are the same, this is self-attention.

Answer (score 0):

One example from [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/qqgeogor/keras-lstm-attention-glove840b-lb-0-043#L51) is available.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However, this doesn't look like a transformer model.